# Docker: How are 2 elasticsearch containers working together?

Tags: elasticsearch, docker, logstash

The production setup for elasticsearch in docker looks like this according the official [website](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/docker.html)

```
version: '2'
services:
  elasticsearch1:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.5.2
    container_name: elasticsearch1
    environment:
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    mem_limit: 1g
    volumes:
      - esdata1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - esnet
  elasticsearch2:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.5.2
    environment:
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - "discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts=elasticsearch1"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    mem_limit: 1g
    volumes:
      - esdata2:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - esnet

volumes:
  esdata1:
    driver: local
  esdata2:
    driver: local

networks:
  esnet:
```

Elasticsearch1 is exposed, and it's also connected with Elasticsearch2 by the docker network but they have their own storage.
Now is my question. How is this setup working? Is ES2 (elasticsearch2) doing nothing till ES1 (elasticsearch1) goes down, or is it replicating everything?

Because when I use the API I will always connect with `localhost:9200` so I will always access ES1. I don't know what ES1 is doing with this information relative to ES2.

Another case is inside my logstash.conf I have to define the destination of my output:

```
output {
  elasticsearch { hosts => ["elasticsearch1:9200"] }
  xxx
}
```

I keep it internal over the docker network (logstash is linked with elasticsearch1) but I don't know if I also have to define elasticsearch2? Or what is happening now.

How are elasticsearch1 and elasticsearch2 working together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two instances act as a cluster. Even if you query one single node, internally your query gets forwarded to all nodes of the cluster (2 in your case) because data is shared across them. Have a look at this official page for more details: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/_basic_concepts.html

Comment: Thanks, I've read it. So if I understand, it's fine to do all my commands/stuff on 1 of the 2 nodes I have inside my ES 'cluster'? I still don't see a very clear explanation about the handling of the data, but I saw the word replica? If I send logs to ES1, they will also be stored inside the data volume of ES2?

Comment: It's an under the hood thing. The fact is that you can reach any of the instances as they were a single big instance. How data is spread across them depends on the configuration but it's somehow transparent for the client.

Comment: so in an ideal situation there is a sort of load balancer above ES so I can touch 1 URL in my configurations and the loadbalancer will route it to one of my ES. If one is down, it will use the other one

Comment: This requires that data is duplicated across all nodes, but I don't think that's always the case. It depends on the cluster configuration.